# Yii 2 MULTILINGUAL WEBSITE

Tags: widget, multilingual, yii2

I am trying to acvhieve multilinguial widget [like this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/) in Yii2

I refereed [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56027-yii2-multilingual-website-url-rules/)

But I am stuck at the last part that is building selector widget. Can anyone list step by step process in Yii2?

Below is my code for the language selector which returns nothing and breaks the layout for now

```
<?php //languageselector.php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

?>

<div id="language-select">
<?php 
if(sizeof($languages) < 4) {
    // Render options as links
    $lastElement = end($languages);
    foreach($languages as $key=>$lang) {
        if($key != $currentLang) {
           echo  $owners->createMultilanguageReturnUrl($key);
            echo Html::a(
                 $lang,
                 $owners->createMultilanguageReturnUrl($key));
        } else echo '<b>'.$lang.'</b>';
        if($lang != $lastElement) echo ' | ';
    }
}
else {
    // Render options as dropDownList
    echo Html::form();
    foreach($languages as $key=>$lang) {
        echo Html::hiddenField(
            $key, 
            $this->createMultilanguageReturnUrl($key));
    }
    echo Html::dropDownList('language', $currentLang, $languages,
        array(
            'submit'=>'',
        )
    ); 
    echo Html::endForm();
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after lots of trial i found solution to my problem.
Please refer below for those who wish to build multilingual widget in yii2

```
<?php
namespace app\components\widgets;
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\base\Widget;
use app\components\views;

class LanguageSelectorPortlet extends Widget
{
public function init(){
    $this->renderContent();
}

public function renderContent()
{
    $currentLang = Yii::$app->language;

    $languages = Yii::$app->params['languages'];
    echo $this->render('languageSelector', array('currentLang' => $currentLang,    'languages'=>$languages));
}
}
```

and the view file for it is as below

```
   <?php
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

  ?>
<div id="language-select">
<?php 

    // Render options as links
    $lastElement = end($languages);
    foreach($languages as $key=>$lang) {
        if($key != $currentLang) {
            echo Html::a($lang,Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createmultiUrl($key));

        } else echo '<b>'.$lang.'</b>';
        if($lang != $lastElement) echo ' | ';
    }


 ?>
</div>
```

Hope that helps someone who is struggling with Multilingual widget in YII2

Comment: does this translates the content of the webiste?